# Android Adding SmallText to textview

Tags: android, textview

I would like to display the following text in the android textview

Test data S (S should be on the top right corner)
    test

Basically I have a text which spans across two lines and I want to add a alphabet at the top right corner of the textview. I tried to use the HTML class with `<sup>` tag but it puts a super script right above the text and not on the top right corner.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try using spannable string.
see this link
[spannable strings](http://androidcocktail.blogspot.in/2014/03/android-spannablestring-example.html)

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("Test data<sup>S</sup>"));
```